# How to convert part of a big std::string into a float efficiently?

Tags: c++, parsing, wavefront

```
void OBJLoader::load_vec(const char* line_prefix) {
size_t jump = 0;
size_t strpos = 0;
if (line_prefix == "v ") {
    while ((strpos = buffer.find(line_prefix, strpos)) != string::npos) {
        strpos++;
        vcoord_vec.emplace_back(stof(&buffer.at(strpos), &jump));
        strpos += jump;
        vcoord_vec.emplace_back(stof(&buffer.at(strpos), &jump));
        strpos += jump;
        vcoord_vec.emplace_back(stof(&buffer.at(strpos), &jump));
        strpos += jump;
    }
    return;
}
//(...)
```

This is the code I use to convert the text inside `buffer` string to float and put it inside a vector. The important part of the string itself has such structure:

```
v -0.893339 0.784809 0.891470
v -0.893339 -0.784809 0.891470
v -0.692655 -0.634043 0.017402
v 0.692655 0.586786 -0.017402
v -0.710057 0.651445 0.000000
v 0.710057 -0.604188 0.000000
v 0.017402 -0.571364 -0.674429
v -0.017402 0.618621 0.674429
v 0.000000 -0.636023 0.691831
```

using `vcoord_vec.emplace_back(stof(&buffer.at(strpos), &jump))` it takes about 200ms to load a single value into a vector while this:

```
void OBJLoader::load_vec(const char* line_prefix) {
    char* cbuffer = const_cast<char*>(buffer.c_str());
    if (line_prefix == "v ") {
        while (cbuffer = strstr(cbuffer, line_prefix)) {
            cbuffer++;
            vcoord_vec.emplace_back(strtof(cbuffer, &cbuffer));
            vcoord_vec.emplace_back(strtof(cbuffer, &cbuffer));
            vcoord_vec.emplace_back(strtof(cbuffer, &cbuffer));
        }
        return;
    }
//(...)
```

loads 4 718 598 of them in 489ms. What would be the "C++ way" of converting a part of a string at known index into whatever type of number with comparable efficiency?

Comment: You should use `std::from_chars` if you have it available.

Comment: "*200ms to load a single value into a vector*": `stof` may be slow, but this seems extremely excessive. Are you sure this isn't a typo (µs?) and did you compile with optimizations on?

Comment: `line_prefix == “v “` that might work with some compilers but you should avoid it. The standard doesn’t say that equal string literals must have equal addresses.

Comment: @uneven_mark I'm positive, optimizations on and it felt like it was copying 250MB worth of string every call. Actually the memory monitor in visual studio was showing weird spikes in usage.

Comment: @BigTemp What type is `buffer`? Have you tried replacing `.at(...)` (which does bound checks for standard containers/strings) with `[...]` (which doesn't)?

Comment: @uneven_mark It's a std::string

Comment: @Jason Yes, the `vcoord_vec` has enough capacity for it to push all of the elements without reallocating

Comment: @BigTemp Btw. If you use `.data()` instead of `.c_str()`, then you don't need the `const_cast`. (Only guaranteed to behave correctly since C++11.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `std::stof` wrong. You are passing it a `char*` when it is expecting a `const std::string&`.

The result of that is an implicit conversion from `char*` to `std::string` in each call to `std::stof`, copying the whole content of `buffer` starting at `strpos` to its null-terminator into the temporary created by the conversion for the function parameter.

Prefer `std::from_chars` if available (C++17) and otherwise I'd suggest sticking with `std::strtof` for the conversion (that does not mean you have to keep using `strstr`). `std::stof` is specified to call `std::strtof` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For really basic formats with space-delimited values like you're using, you can use C++ streams:

```cpp
#include <sstream>

/*...*/

char id; 
float v[3];

std::istringstream iss("v 123.4 12.5 0262.2");
iss >> id;
if (id == 'v') {
    iss >> v[0] >> v[1] >> v[2];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a utility class that I use within my 3D Graphics engines. For this to work with my example you'll need to have a version of the GLM library available, otherwise you can comment out all of the GLM related stuff to do simple basic conversion of single values. However, I'm showing it here as a demonstration of how to convert from a string to different numerical types including user defined types.

You can not construct an instance of this Utility class object as its constructor is deleted and it has no member variables. It is only a collection of similar or related functions, mostly `string` manipulation methods.

If you take the time to read through the class you will see that I am using static functions to convert from string to the wanted types.

The class does have 2 private function templates, `string_to_value` which is defined in the header outside of the class and `get_value` which is defined in the cpp file as there are 3 overloaded or `template specialization` functions based on the return types. They are `int`, `unsigned` and `float`, respectively. I have also included overloaded `operator<<`'s for all of the glm vector types for easy printing.

It is within the `get_value` functions that I use `std::stof`, `std::stoi` and `std::stoul`. If you want to add the ability to convert to `double` it shouldn't be that hard to add it to this class.

My class is much bigger than this, but to keep it short I've omitted at least half of it.

---

Now for the code...

**Application and Output**

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Utility.h"

int main() {
    using namespace util;

    try {
        std::string str1("3,4,5");
        std::string str2("-4,-2,7");
        std::string str3("2.4,7.8,9.2");      

        glm::uvec3 uvec3 = Utility::convert_to_uvec3(str1);
        glm::ivec3 ivec3 = Utility::convert_to_ivec3(str2);
        glm::vec3   vec3 = Utility::convert_to_vec3(str3);

        std::cout << uvec3 << '\n';
        std::cout << ivec3 << '\n';       
        std::cout <<  vec3 << '\n';

        // test an exception case:
        glm::vec4 v4 = Utility::convert_to_vec4(str2);

    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

*Output*

```
(3,4,5)
(-4,-2,7)
(2.4,7.8,9.2)
util::Utility::convert_to_vec4 Bad conversion of [-4,-2,7] to vec4
```

---

**Utility Class**

*Utility.h*

```
#ifndef UTILITY_H
#define UTILITY_H

#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

namespace util {

    class Utility {
    public:
        static std::string to_upper(const std::string& str);
        static std::string to_lower(const std::string& str);
        static std::string trim(const std::string& str, const std::string elements_to_trim = " \t\n\r");

        static unsigned     convert_to_unsigned(const std::string& str);
        static int          convert_to_int(const std::string& str);
        static float        convert_to_float(const std::string& str);

        static glm::vec2    convert_to_vec2(const std::string& str);
        static glm::vec3    convert_to_vec3(const std::string& str);
        static glm::vec4    convert_to_vec4(const std::string& str);

        static glm::ivec2   convert_to_ivec2(const std::string& str);
        static glm::ivec3   convert_to_ivec3(const std::string& str);
        static glm::ivec4   convert_to_ivec4(const std::string& str);

        static glm::uvec2   convert_to_uvec2(const std::string& str);
        static glm::uvec3   convert_to_uvec3(const std::string& str);
        static glm::uvec4   convert_to_uvec4(const std::string& str);

    private:
        Utility() = delete;
        Utility(const Utility& c) = delete;
        Utility& operator=(const Utility& c) = delete;

        template<typename T>
        static bool string_to_value(const std::string& str, T* value, unsigned num_values);

        template<typename T>
        static T get_value(const std::string& str, std::size_t& remainder);
    };

    template<typename T>
    static bool Utility::string_to_value(const std::string& str, T* value, unsigned num_values) {
        int num_commas = std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), ',');
        if (num_commas != num_values - 1) return false;

        std::size_t remainder;
        value[0] = get_value<T>(str, remainder);

        if (num_values == 1) {
            if (str.size() != remainder) {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            std::size_t offset = remainder;
            if (str.at(offset) != ',') {
                return false;
            }

            unsigned last_indx = num_values - 1;
            for (unsigned u = 1; u < num_values; ++u) {
                value[u] = get_value<T>(str.substr(++offset), remainder);
                offset += remainder;
                if ((u < last_indx && str.at(offset) != ',') ||
                    (u == last_indx && offset != str.size())) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

} // namespace util

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const glm::ivec2& v2Value);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const glm::ivec3& v3Value);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const glm::ivec4& v4Value);

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const glm::vec2& v2Value);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const glm::vec3& v3Value);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const glm::vec4& v4Value);

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const glm::uvec2& v2Value);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const glm::uvec3& v3Value);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const glm::uvec4& v4Value);

#endif // UTILITY_H
```

*Utility.cpp*

```
#include "Utility.h"

#include <exception>
#include <sstream>

namespace util {
    std::string Utility::to_upper(const std::string& str) {
        std::string result = str;
        std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), result.begin(), ::toupper);
        return result;
    }

    std::string Utility::to_lower(const std::string& str) {
        std::string result = str;
        std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), result.begin(), ::tolower);
        return result;
    }

    std::string Utility::trim(const std::string& str, const std::string elements_to_trim) {
        std::basic_string<char>::size_type first_index = str.find_first_not_of(elements_to_trim);
        if (first_index == std::string::npos) {
            return std::string(); // nothing left
        }

        std::basic_string<char>::size_type last_index = str.find_last_not_of(elements_to_trim);
        return str.substr(first_index, last_index - first_index + 1);
    }

    template<>
    float Utility::get_value(const std::string& str, std::size_t& remainder) {
        return std::stof(str, &remainder);
    } // getValue<float>

    template<>
    int Utility::get_value(const std::string& str, std::size_t& remainder) {
        return std::stoi(str, &remainder);
    } // getValue<int>

    template<>
    unsigned Utility::get_value(const std::string& str, std::size_t& remainder) {
        return std::stoul(str, &remainder);
    } // getValue<unsigned>

    unsigned Utility::convert_to_unsigned(const std::string& str) {
        unsigned u = 0;
        if (!string_to_value(str, &u, 1)) {
            std::ostringstream stream;
            // __FUNCTION__ works on windows otherwise user can exchange - modify to use __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
            stream << __FUNCTION__ << " Bad conversion of [" << str << "] to unsigned";
            throw std::exception(stream.str().c_str());
        }
        return u;
    }

    int Utility::convert_to_int(const std::string& str) {
        int i = 0;
        if (!string_to_value(str, &i, 1)) {
            std::ostringstream stream;
            // __FUNCTION__ works on windows otherwise user can exchange - modify to use __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
            stream << __FUNCTION__ << " Bad conversion of [" << str << "] to int";
            throw std::exception(stream.str().c_str());
        }
        return i;
    }

    float Utility::convert_to_float(const std::string& str) {
        float f = 0;
        if (!string_to_value(str, &f, 1)) {
            std::ostringstream stream;
            // __FUNCTION__ works on windows otherwise user can exchange - modify to use __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
            stream << __FUNCTION__ << " Bad conversion of [" << str << "] to float";
            throw std::exception(stream.str().c_str());
        }
        return f;
    }

    glm::vec2 Utility::convert_to_vec2(const std::string& str) {
        glm::vec2 v2;
        if (!string_to_value(str, &v2[0], 2)) {
            std::ostringstream stream;
            // __FUNCTION__ works on windows otherwise user can exchange - modify to use __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
            stream << __FUNCTION__ << " Bad conversion of [" << str << "] to vec2";
            throw std::exception(stream.str().c_str());
        }
        return v2;
    }

    glm::vec3 Utility::convert_to_vec3(const std::string& str) {
        glm::vec3 v3;
        if (!string_to_value(str, &v3[0], 3)) {
            std::ostringstream stream;
            // __FUNCTION__ works on windows otherwise user can exchange - modify to use __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
            stream << __FUNCTION__ << " Bad conversion of [" << str << "] to vec3";
            throw std::exception(stream.str().c_str());
        }
        return v3;
    }

    glm::vec4 Utility::convert_to_vec4(const std::string& str) {
        glm::vec4 v4;
        if (!string_to_value(str, &v4[0], 4)) {
            std::ostringstream stream;
            // __FUNCTION__ works on windows otherwise user can exchange - modify to use __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
            stream << __FUNCTION__ << " Bad conversion of [" << str << "] to vec4";
            throw std::exception(stream.str().c_str());
        }
        return v4;
    }

    glm::ivec2 Utility::convert_to_ivec2(const std::string& str) {
        glm::ivec2 v2;
        if (!string_to_value(str, &v2[0], 2)) {
            std::ostringstream stream;
            // __FUNCTION__ works on windows otherwise user can exchange - modify to use __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
            stream << __FUNCTION__ << " Bad conversion of [" << str << "] to ivec2";
            throw std::exception(stream.str().c_str());
        }
        return v2;
    }

    glm::ivec3 Utility::convert_to_ivec3(const std::string& str) {
        glm::ivec3 v3;
        if (!string_to_value(str, &v3[0], 3)) {
            std::ostringstream stream;
            // __FUNCTION__ works on windows otherwise user can exchange - modify to use __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
            stream << __FUNCTION__ << " Bad conversion of [" << str << "] to ivec3";
            throw std::exception(stream.str().c_str());
        }
        return v3;
    }

    glm::ivec4 Utility::convert_to_ivec4(const std::string& str) {
        glm::ivec4 v4;
        if (!string_to_value(str, &v4[0], 4)) {
            std::ostringstream stream;
            // __FUNCTION__ works on windows otherwise user can exchange - modify to use __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
            stream << __FUNCTION__ << " Bad conversion of [" << str << "] to ivec4";
            throw std::exception(stream.str().c_str());
        }
        return v4;
    }

    glm::uvec2 Utility::convert_to_uvec2(const std::string& str) {
        glm::uvec2 v2;
        if (!string_to_value(str, &v2[0], 2)) {
            std::ostringstream stream;
            // __FUNCTION__ works on windows otherwise user can exchange - modify to use __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
            stream << __FUNCTION__ << " Bad conversion of [" << str << "] to uvec2";
            throw std::exception(stream.str().c_str());
        }
        return v2;
    }

    glm::uvec3 Utility::convert_to_uvec3(const std::string& str) {
        glm::uvec3 v3;
        if (!string_to_value(str, &v3[0], 3)) {
            std::ostringstream stream;
            // __FUNCTION__ works on windows otherwise user can exchange - modify to use __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
            stream << __FUNCTION__ << " Bad conversion of [" << str << "] to uvec3";
            throw std::exception(stream.str().c_str());
        }
        return v3;
    }

    glm::uvec4 Utility::convert_to_uvec4(const std::string& str) {
        glm::uvec4 v4;
        if (!string_to_value(str, &v4[0], 4)) {
            std::ostringstream stream;
            // __FUNCTION__ works on windows otherwise user can exchange - modify to use __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
            stream << __FUNCTION__ << " Bad conversion of [" << str << "] to uvec4";
            throw std::exception(stream.str().c_str());
        }
        return v4;
    }

} // namespace util

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const glm::ivec2& v2Value) {
    out << "("
        << v2Value.x << ","
        << v2Value.y << ")";
    return out;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const glm::ivec3& v3Value) {
    out << "("
        << v3Value.x << ","
        << v3Value.y << ","
        << v3Value.z << ")";
    return out;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const glm::ivec4& v4Value) {
    out << "("
        << v4Value.x << ","
        << v4Value.y << ","
        << v4Value.z << ","
        << v4Value.w << ")";
    return out;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const glm::vec2& v2Value) {
    out << "("
        << v2Value.x << ","
        << v2Value.y << ")";
    return out;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const glm::vec3& v3Value) {
    out << "("
        << v3Value.x << ","
        << v3Value.y << ","
        << v3Value.z << ")";
    return out;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const glm::vec4& v4Value) {
    out << "("
        << v4Value.x << ","
        << v4Value.y << ","
        << v4Value.z << ","
        << v4Value.w << ")";
    return out;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const glm::uvec2& v2Value) {
    out << "("
        << v2Value.x << ","
        << v2Value.y << ")";
    return out;
} 

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const glm::uvec3& v3Value) {
    out << "("
        << v3Value.x << ","
        << v3Value.y << ","
        << v3Value.z << ")";
    return out;
} 

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const glm::uvec4& v4Value) {
    out << "("
        << v4Value.x << ","
        << v4Value.y << ","
        << v4Value.z << ","
        << v4Value.w << ")";
    return out;
}
```

---

**Note:**

In my `string_to_value` function I'm using a comma as a delimiter or string separator. You can easily change this to a space or some other character and it should give you the same functionality...